# redsocks + socks server on different machine

Tags: iptables, proxy, forwarding, transparent-proxy, socks

I have the following setup:

- Host-X (192.168.1.100) running ssh -D so that it can be used as a socks server.
- Host-Y (192.168.1.101) running redsocks configured with Host-X as socks.

They are in the same network together with other machines. I would like to use Host-Y as gateway on some computers to take advantage of redsocks. IP forwarding on Host-Y is enabled.

This is redsocks configuration:

```
base {
    log_info = on;
    log = "file:/var/log/redsocks.log";
    daemon = on;
    redirector = iptables;
}
redsocks {
    local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_port = 2001;
    ip = 192.168.1.100;
    port = 2000;
    type = socks5;
}
```

These are my iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 2001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

I can see the traffic coming to redsocks on Host-Y from the log, but I can't browse the Internet on the computers that use Host-Y as gateway. Obviously there are some iptables rules missing, I guess one that send redsocks output traffic to the socks server. Anyone who can help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if I put the last rule as the first one, everything works correctly. So the solution is to use the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 2001
```